# Prove that $B \setminus (B \setminus A) = A$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Prove that $B \setminus (B \setminus A) = A$

My conclusion is that  $B \setminus (B \setminus A) \neq A$, OR, to be precise, $B \setminus (B \setminus A) = A \cap B$.

[image]

If I'm wrong, please help me prove it. If I'm correct, how should I show that the question asked cannot be proved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $B\setminus X\subseteq B$, for every set $X$, a *necessary* condition for $B\setminus(B\setminus A)=A$ to hold is that $A\subseteq B$.

So just take $A$ any nonempty set and $B=\emptyset$ to get your counterexample.

Your conjecture is good: indeed $B\setminus(B\setminus A)=A\cap B$. You can prove it algebraically: if $U=A\cup B$ (or $U$ is any set containing both $A$ and $B$), we can denote $X'=U\setminus X$, when $X\subseteq U$. Then $B\setminus X=B\cap X'$ and so
\begin{align}
B\setminus(B\setminus A)
&= B\cap(B\setminus A)' && \text{(identity above)} \\
&= B\cap(B\cap A')' && \text{(identity above)} \\
&= B\cap(B'\cup A) && \text{(De Morgan)} \\
&= (B\cap B')\cup (B\cap A) && \text{(distributivity)} \\
&= \emptyset\cup(A\cap B) && \text{(commutativity)} \\
&= A\cap B
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

You're correct. We can disprove via counterexample. Suppose that:
\begin{align*}
A &= \{1, 2\} \\
B &= \{2, 3\}
\end{align*}
Then observe that:
$$
B \setminus (B \setminus A)
= B \setminus \{3\}
= \{2\}
\neq \{1, 2\} = A
$$

Answer (score 2):

A truth table can be used as a logical Venn diagram. Each disjoint area in a Venn diagram corresponds to the appropriate member functions.

Using the definition $x\in B\setminus A\equiv x\in B \land x\notin A$ gives the following truth table.

| $x\in A$ | $x\in B$ | $x\in B\setminus A$ | $x\in B\setminus(B\setminus A)$ | $x\in A\cap B$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $0$ | $0$ | $0$ | $0$ | $0$ |
| $0$ | $1$ | $1$ | $0$ | $0$ |
| $1$ | $0$ | $0$ | $0$ | $0$ |
| $1$ | $1$ | $0$ | $1$ | $1$ |

As the last two columns are identical, we can conclude that $B\setminus(B\setminus A)\equiv A\cap B$.

A counter-example to the original conjecture is any $A\ne\emptyset$ such that $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Comment: Since the notation $\subset$ is used in two different ways, not all readers may understand that $\emptyset \subset A$ means the empty set is a proper subset of $A$.  You could just say that $A$ is a nonempty set.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig; fixed.